# Which mvc3 / c# technology/architecture are we really looking for - nservicebus, WCF or something else?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, nservicebus

Here's what we need to do.

We have a web application (MVC3) that allows various entities to be managed. Let's say "schools", "students" and "teachers".

When any of these entities changes (created, updated or deleted) we need to tell another system about the change. We're not in control of that other system, but we have access to a web service that lets us make real time updates to it.

I know I don't want our users to wait around while we connect to this web service and make the updates, so we must need a way to queue updates and make the changes as part of a totally separate process.

I'd really appreciate any architectural pointers for solving this problem. I'm sure there are existing frameworks that will manage this queue and let us, for instance, resend data if communications are interrupted - but I don't know which frameworks to look at.

Cheers!

Comment: Read about CQRS and service bus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NServicebus would provide the queueing you require.  It provides transactional support, and a return to source queue utility in the case that you need to re-process a failed message.  I would recommend a third system here to deal with calling the web service.  This message handler would read from the queue and call the web service.

Client ->  Publish NServiceBus Msg -> MessageHandler -> Web Service

This message handler will then give you the separation of concerns that you require.

Comment: Thanks, John - that's very helpful. Good to know I wasn't totally wide of the mark thinking of NServiceBus. With this, how does the object that changed (the "teacher" record, or whatever) get persisted into the queue? Is is the original C# object or a serialized object, or something else?

Comment: Typically you would use a DTO for the message data and make that a property of a class that implements IMessage.

Answer (score 0):

The other vendor/client that needs data updates is not dependent on your application. At least not from your explanation. They are dependent on accurate data. This means your issue is a data issue, not an application issue. From that standpoint, a data solution looks sexy.

If you are using SQL Server, I would consider using triggers on the database and initiating there. If you want to completely offload the work from both the database operations and the application, then SQL Server Service Broker works nicely.

If you are on another database platform, you may or many not have a queueing service. In these cases, you might require a service bus, but I would see if there is a simpler reliable async method you could use first.

Comment: Thanks, Gregory. It's true that the other system only cares about accurate data. We won't be able to integrate with that system at the database level though, only through a RESTful web service they'll provide.